# Cycle through a list of webpages every 30seconds (Update pages every 30mins??)

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML code

What is the code needed to store a number of different webpages and cycle through them every 30seconds? (The webpages need to be updated every 30mins)

Comment: This question is a bit too general. Please edit the question to make it a bit more specific. For example, do you need to know how to capture an image of a web page? To turn images into a slide show? etc…

Comment: I wouldn't think this would be a good question if you are new to HTML. You should look at many tutorials and learn from that and when you get the idea on how web development works, you can ask that question again.... All I'm saying is, don't try to jump to a difficult topic if you are new to this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If a request every 30 seconds is going to take down your servers, it's time for a new server and/or application rewrite.